# Why do these two methods yield different results?

Tags: arrays, ruby, append

According to all documentation, you can append an element to an array using `<<` or `.push` or `+=`, and the result ought to be the same. I have found it isn't. Can anybody explain to me what I am getting wrong? (I am using Ruby 2.3.1.)

I have got a number of hashes. All of them contain the same keys. I would like to combine them to form one hash with all the collected values in an array. This is straightforward, you iterate through all the hashes and make a new one, collecting all the values like this:

```
    # arg is array of Hashes - keys must be identical
    return {} unless arg
    keys = (arg[0] ? arg[0].keys : [])

    result = keys.product([[]]).to_h # value for each key is empty array.

    arg.each do |h|
      h.each { |k,v| result[k] += [v] }
    end

    result
  end
```

If *instead of* using `+=` I use `.push` or `<<`, I get completely weird results.

Using the following test array:

```
a_of_h = [{"1"=>10, "2"=>10, "3"=>10, "4"=>10, "5"=>10, "6"=>10, "7"=>10, "8"=>10, "9"=>10, "10"=>10}, {"1"=>100, "2"=>100, "3"=>100, "4"=>100, "5"=>100, "6"=>100, "7"=>100, "8"=>100, "9"=>100, "10"=>100}, {"1"=>1000, "2"=>1000, "3"=>1000, "4"=>1000, "5"=>1000, "6"=>1000, "7"=>1000, "8"=>1000, "9"=>1000, "10"=>1000}, {"1"=>10000, "2"=>10000, "3"=>10000, "4"=>10000, "5"=>10000, "6"=>10000, "7"=>10000, "8"=>10000, "9"=>10000, "10"=>10000}]
```

I get

```
merge_hashes(a_of_h)
 => {"1"=>[10, 100, 1000, 10000], "2"=>[10, 100, 1000, 10000], "3"=>[10, 100, 1000, 10000], "4"=>[10, 100, 1000, 10000], "5"=>[10, 100, 1000, 10000], "6"=>[10, 100, 1000, 10000], "7"=>[10, 100, 1000, 10000], "8"=>[10, 100, 1000, 10000], "9"=>[10, 100, 1000, 10000], "10"=>[10, 100, 1000, 10000]}
```

as I expect, but if I use `h.each { |k,v| result[k] << v }` instead I get

```
buggy_merge_hashes(a_of_h)
 => {"1"=>[10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000], "2"=>[10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000], "3"=>[10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000], "4"=>[10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000], "5"=>[10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000], ...}
```

(I cut the rest.)

What is it I don't know here?

Comment: "According to all documentation, you can append an element to an array using `<<` or `.push` or `+=`, **and the result ought to be the same**." – Please, tell us where you found this "all documentation", so that we can eradicate it from this universe with extreme prejudice, because it is just plain wrong. And very obviously so, as you discovered. Also, please use the official documentation, which very clearly does *not* state what you claim "all documentation" states.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag: here, for instance: https://teamtreehouse.com/library/adding-items-to-arrays-2. Or here: https://www.ruby-forum.com/t/add-element-at-end-of-array/106609. Just for a start.

Comment: ...And frankly, I still don't see why it is just plain wrong; all three methods modify the array and attach the new element at the end. As Amadan wrote up so beautifully, my error was completely elsewhere.

Comment: Yes and no. `array += element` does _not_ modify the array. It makes a new array, then discards the old array. Imagine if you need more beer in your fridge. You could buy more beer and just put it into the fridge (`fridge << beer`, `fridge.push(beer)`), or you could buy a new fridge, move everything from the old one to the new one together with the beer you bought, then throw the old fridge away (`fridge = fridge + beer`, `fridge += beer`).

Comment: I would like to point out that neither of the two links you provided are documentation. The second one is just a discussion between a bunch of random people on a mailing list, and the first one is a course by some random guy on the Internet. Also, *nowhere* in the second link does someone claim that those three expressions are equivalent, in fact `+=` is not even mentioned once. I cannot comment on the first link as it requires me to pay to watch the video. However, if the video does not explain the difference between mutation and re-binding, I would ask for your money back.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag: OK, so they aren't documentation. Satisfied? In future, if I don't know how to do something in Ruby I'll go to the documentation. Which means, in particular, I may not go to Stack Exchange, since it is not documentation. And again, the problem was *not* the array manipulation, it was the initialisation of the hash that was all wrong! If I had done the initialisation of my hash correctly, all three methods for adding an element to the array would have yielded the same, correct, result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<<` and `#push` are destructive operations (they change the receiver).

`+` (and consequently `+=` as well) is a non-destructive operation (it returns a new object, leaving the receiver unchanged).

While they seem to be doing the same thing, this apparently small difference is crucial.

This comes into play due to another error: all of your subarrays in `result` start off as the same object. If you add to one of them, you add to all of them.

Why is this not an issue if you use `+=`? Because `result[k] += [v]` is the same as `result[k] = result[k] += [v]` (I'm lying here, there's a subtle difference, but it is not relevant here and just accept that they're the same for now to not get more confused :D ); and as `+` is non-destructive, `result[k] + [v]` is a different object than `result[k]`; when you update the value in the array with this assignment, you are not using the starting `[]` object any more, and the reference sharing error can't bite you any more.

A better way to create your `result` array would be one of these:

```
result = Array.new(keys.size) { [] }
result = keys.map { [] }
```

which will create a new array object for each element.

However, I would write it all quite differently:

```
a_of_h.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }) { |h, r|
  h.each { |k, v| r[k] << v }
}
```

`each_with_hash` will give the passed object to the block as an additional argument (here `r`, for result), and will return it when the method is done. The argument — the object that will be in `r` — will be a hash with a `default_proc`: every time we try to get a key that's not inside yet, it will insert a new array there (i.e. instead of trying to pre-populate our result object, do it on-demand). Then we just go through each of the hashes in your array, and insert the value into the result hash without worrying if the key is there or not.

Comment: I had your same advice, until I tried: `h = { a: [], b: [] }; 2.times { h[:a] += [1] }; 2.times { h[:b] << 1 }`. Or my try to reproduce the issue is missing something?

Comment: Your `h[:a]` and `h[:b]` are distinct objects. Try this for the easiest way to illustrate the difference: `a = [[], []]; a[0]<<1; p a` and `a = [[]] * 2; a[0]<<1; p a`.

Comment: Also, hop [here](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) - the best teaching tool for this concept I know of. Choose Ruby, put in some code (e.g. the two snippets I just posted, or your original code), submit with the "Visualize Execution" button, then step through your code while watching what's happening in the memory.

Comment: Still confused, see `b = [[]] * 2; b[0]+=[1]; p b`, it's the same as your first`a = [[], []]; a[0]<<1; p a`. Great link, by the way. Thanks!

Comment: When `result = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }` there is no difference between the two methods. When `result = Hash.new([])`, the buggy method returns `{}`. I'm on my way... :)

Comment: When you're using `+=` and overwriting the array, so destructive and nondestructive methods will work the same as long as there is no reference sharing. My `result` prevents reference sharing; yours ensures it. Do execute things in the visualiser, and I believe a lot of things will become clearer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So my original error was that I didn't use the `.product` method correctly. This is a very valuable insight. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The first one does `hash[key] += value`. The second one does `hash[key] << value`.

Comment: You're stating the obvious. Your answer should explain why the two operators behave differently, and why that difference leads to the problem OP has.