# Ruby map, map! modifying array of hashes

Tags: ruby

So `map` vs `map!`

```
foo = [1,2,3]
foo.map { |i| i*=2}
=> [2, 4, 6]
foo
=> [1, 2, 3] # foo unchanged

foo.map! { |i| i*=2}
=> [2, 4, 6]
foo
=> [2, 4, 6] # foo is changed
```

All good/expected. Now with Array of `hash`, let's do `map`:

```
bar =  [{foo:1,bar:11}, {foo:2,bar:12}, {foo:3,bar:13}]
=> [{:foo=>1, :bar=>11}, {:foo=>2, :bar=>12}, {:foo=>3, :bar=>13}]
bar.map { |i| i[:foo]*= 2}
=> [2, 4, 6]
bar
=> [{:foo=>2, :bar=>11}, {:foo=>4, :bar=>12}, {:foo=>6, :bar=>13}] # changed
```

So it seems that the underlying array of hashes were modified using `map`, and essentially is the same as `map!`:

```
bar.map! do |i| 
 i[:foo]*=2 
 i 
end
=> [{:foo=>2, :bar=>11}, {:foo=>4, :bar=>12}, {:foo=>6, :bar=>13}]
bar
=> [{:foo=>2, :bar=>11}, {:foo=>4, :bar=>12}, {:foo=>6, :bar=>13}]
```

Probably missing something fundamental here. Not looking for alternatives, just trying to understand what *seems* to be an undocumented(?) note/gotcha/inconsistency. Tnx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `map` method does not change the array's contents, as can be seen by inspecting the `object_id` of each element of the array.  However, each element is a hash, which is mutable, so updating the contents of the hash is permissible.  This can be seen from the following step-by-step trace of the results:

```
p baz = [{foo:1,bar:11}, {foo:2,bar:12}, {foo:3,bar:13}]
puts "baz contents IDs are:"
baz.each { |hsh| p hsh.object_id }
puts "performing the map operation"
p baz.map { |i| i[:foo] *= 2 }
puts "baz contents IDs still are:"
baz.each { |hsh| p hsh.object_id }
puts "...but the contents of those contents have changed:"
p baz
```

which produces, e.g.:

```
[{:foo=>1, :bar=>11}, {:foo=>2, :bar=>12}, {:foo=>3, :bar=>13}]
baz contents IDs are:
70261047089900
70261047089860
70261047089840
performing the map operation:
[2, 4, 6]
baz contents IDs still are:
70261047089900
70261047089860
70261047089840
...but the contents of those contents have changed:
[{:foo=>2, :bar=>11}, {:foo=>4, :bar=>12}, {:foo=>6, :bar=>13}]
```

Note that I changed the name of the array to `baz` to avoid any confusion due to name shadowing.

Comment: Thank you, _"hash is mutable"_ was how I was making sense of it. IMHO, worth a note in documentation(?) of `map`, `map!`....

Comment: It might be worth suggesting a comment in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Let's compare the value of `i` in your first example:

```
foo = [1,2,3]
foo.map { |i| i*=2}
```

`i` here is a number. Numbers are immutable. Thus writing `i * 2` or `i *= 2` in the block makes no difference. The assignment doesn't propogate anywhere, no matter if you use `map` or `map!`.

Why doesn't the assignment matter, even if you use `map!` ? We can re-implement `map!` quickly to understand:

```
def my_map!(list, &blk)
  list.each_index { |i| list[i] = blk.call(list[i]) }
  list
end
```

As you can see, we're setting the value of each index to the *return value of the block*. And the *return value* of `i * 2` or `i *= 2` is the same.

Now, looking at the second example:

```
bar =  [{foo:1,bar:11}, {foo:2,bar:12}, {foo:3,bar:13}]
bar.map { |i| i[:foo]*= 2}
```

Why does this mutate the hashes? The value of `i` here is a Hash, which *is mutable*. Assigning a key-val (`i[:foo]*= 2`) mutates it, regardless of if it happens in `each`, `map`, `map!`, etc.

So, to cut to the chase, you would want to create a new hash using something like `merge` or `dup`:

```
bar =  [{foo:1,bar:11}, {foo:2,bar:12}, {foo:3,bar:13}]
bar.map { |i| i.merge(foo: i[:foo] * 2) }
```

Comment: Thank you - _"The value of i here is a Hash, which is **mutable**"_ - this was how I was groking it.

Comment: Can you pls clarify _"The assignment doesn't propogate anywhere, no matter if you use `map` or `map!`"_  - re: `map!` assigns the new value as expected (in first example Array<number>)

Comment: @EdSF I can try ... consider `[1,2,3].each { |i| i = 5000 }`. What's getting assigned to 5000 here? The variable `i`, which is redefined each block.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add my two cents.

When you use the exact same code (`e[:foo] *= 2`) in the block you can see that `map` and `map!` differs.

---

**Using `map`**

```
bar =  [ {foo:1, bar:11}, {foo:2, bar:12}, {foo:3, bar:13} ]
bar.map { |e| e[:foo] *= 2 } #=> [2, 4, 6]
bar #=> [{:foo=>2, :bar=>11}, {:foo=>4, :bar=>12}, {:foo=>6, :bar=>13}]
```

On `bar` you get the exact same effect as using `each`, except for the returning value of the call:

```
bar =  [ {foo:1, bar:11}, {foo:2, bar:12}, {foo:3, bar:13} ]
bar.each { |e| e[:foo] *= 2 } #=> [{:foo=>2, :bar=>11}, {:foo=>4, :bar=>12}, {:foo=>6, :bar=>13}]
bar #=> [{:foo=>2, :bar=>11}, {:foo=>4, :bar=>12}, {:foo=>6, :bar=>13}]
```

---

**Using `map!`**

```
bar =  [ {foo:1, bar:11}, {foo:2, bar:12}, {foo:3, bar:13} ]
bar.map! { |e| e[:foo] *= 2 } #=> [2, 4, 6]
bar #=> [2, 4, 6]
```

---

[Once @Amadam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57270113/5239030) gave me a link to a really useful tool to understand what's going on during the execution of the code, maybe could help further: http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit

Comment: Thank you - yup, understand that. I'm more into what happens to the underlying/original array, with `map` - re: it _does_ change contrary to what one might think depending on mutability.